# Plot Shows Random Bar Graph and Wrong data of each time in Ploty Graph

Tags: python, graph, bar-chart, plotly

Python 3.5
Plotly offline

The below code successfully generating output however the outputs are random and not showing all the X axis data in a bar graph.

Input from .tab file (table as shown below)
output : plotting the below table as BAR graph

```
[Function group][count]


ke1           101
IO1            70
Andr1234       22
VN1            22
NAV1           20
SW1            17
DC123          16
OnOff          15
Linux          12
AD1            12
Brow1          10
QNXOS           9
OSSDK           9
DM1             7
Frm1            6
SYSINT          5
TABA1           4
Security        3
A1              3
DCM             3
Per1            2
Trace           2
Audio           1
Buildtools      1
ENV             1
Pathology       1
```

When i plot this using plotly it shows random bar and not all the title is shown in the column1 coming in the graph.

What is the code change required to get all the X-axis names and its corresponding Y-axis is counted as per the table above?

1. Every time I run this code it generates a random value graph and random X axis text.Not all the text label in the table shown in the X-axis,only 10-12 label shown.How to overcome this issue and plot right BAR graph with right value for each table labels.
2. What needs to be added to show the count on the BAR without hovering mouse.

---

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from nsepy import get_history

import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

datalist = pd.read_table(r'D:\python\ython\xxx.tab',sep='\t')   #sep=\s+|\t+
datalistFg=pd.value_counts(datalist['Function group'].values, sort=True)
datalistRp=pd.value_counts(datalist['Responsible person'].values, sort=True)


print(datalistFg)

#graphing place
otrace1 =go.Bar(
    #x=stock_opt_pe.index
    x=datalist['Function group'],
    y=datalistFg,
    text=datalistFg,
    #xaxis-type (enumerated: “-” | “linear” | “log” | “date” | “category” )
    #xaxis-type (enumerated: “-” | “linear” | “log” | “date” | “category” )
    #name='Function Group Vx RespPerson',
    #orientation = 'v',
    #marker = dict(
        #color = 'rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.6)',
        #line = dict(
            #color = 'rgba(246, 250, 206, 1.0)',
            #color = 'rgb(60, 60, 60)',
            #width = 0)
    #)
)

otrace2 = go.Bar(
    #x=stock_opt_pe.index
    x=datalist['Responsible person'],
    y=datalistRp,
    name='RP',
    orientation = 'v',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(128, 255, 0, 0.6)',
        line = dict(
            #color = 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 1.0)',
            #color = 'rgb(204, 255, 204)',
            width = 1.5)
    )
)

odata = [otrace1]
olayout = go.Layout(
    title = "TESTING",
    xaxis=dict(
    tickangle=35,
    showticklabels=True,
    type='category',
    title='Function group',
    tickmode='linear'),
#    barmode="linear"
)
fig = dict(data=odata, layout=olayout)
#fig = dict(data=odata)
iplot(fig, filename = 'D:/python/ython/Test-{}.html'.format("Testing"))
plot(fig,show_link = True, filename = 'D:/python/ython/test_{}.html'.format("Testing"))
```

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This below update solved the problem .Only one issue is that X axis is showing 1 2 ,3....25 .If this is corrected to show the X axis label for each bar as Ke1,IO1,VN1.... this solution will be complete.

Now the plotting is correctly working except the X axis labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly
plotly.__version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

datalist = pd.read_table(r'D:\pon\oon\etml\106111025170_20180808062710.tab',sep='\t')   #sep=\s+|\t+

#graph plotly
otrace1 =go.Bar(
    x=datalist['Function group'].nunique(),
    y=pd.value_counts(datalist['Function group'].values,sort=True),
    text=pd.value_counts(datalist['Function group'].values,sort=True),
    textposition = 'auto',
    orientation = 'v',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgba(127,87,225,1.00)',
        line = dict(
            color = 'rgba(127,45,64,1.00)',
            width = 0),
    )
)

odata = [otrace1]
olayout = go.Layout(
    title = "TESTING",
    xaxis=dict(
    #tickangle=35,
    #showticklabels=True,
    #type='category',
    title='GroupName',
    titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#ffff7f'
        ),
    tickmode='linear'),
    barmode="bar"
)
fig = dict(data=odata, layout=olayout)
#fig = dict(data=odata)
iplot(fig, filename = 'D:/pyon/ofhon/elml/Test-{}.html'.format("Testing"))
plot(fig,show_link = True, filename = 'D:/pyon/ofhon/elml/test_{}.html'.format("Testing"))
```